# A basic question on group cohomology

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology

I am studying group cohomology, and those constructs are a bit abstract to me, I can't even write down a concrete example. For example, I'm having some trouble understanding the following assertion: if $H$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$, and $A$ is a $G$-module, then cohomology group $H^n(H,A)$ is a $G/H$-module. Let us consider the simplest case as follows: assume that $H$ acts trivially on $A$ and $n=1$, then $H^1(H,A)=\text{Hom}(H,A)$. So, how to define a $G/H$-action on $\text{Hom}(H,A)$ explicitly in this case?

Comment: If $H$is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $A$ is a $G$-module, then we have for each $g\in G$ the compatible pair given by $(h\mapsto g^{-1}hg, a\mapsto ga)$. This induces the conjugation action of $G/H$ on $H^n(H,A)$.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is that one defines
$$(g\cdot\phi)(h)=\phi(g^{-1}hg)$$

But I'd like to say a couple of things about your comment on the abstractness of group cohomology. I've found two concrete example helped me considerably.

The first are the so-called wallpaper groups, the two-dimensional cystallographic groups. The module here is just $\mathbb{R}^2$, and the groups are discrete geometric symmetries. Howard Hiller wrote an article on this, "Crystallography and Cohomology of Groups", which won an MAA Writing Award. See [here](https://diagonalargument.com/2020/04/26/wallpaper-groups/) for more, including links.

Here's how that action looks in a specific case. Consider the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2$ of all integral points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $G$ be the group of symmetries, $T$ the normal subgroup of translations; $A=\mathbb{Z}^2$ is our module, and $T$ acts on $A$ via translation. Then if $g\in G$ is, say, a $90^\circ$ rotation of the lattice, $g^{-1}tg$ will be the translation rotated by $90^\circ$. Finally, if $\phi$ is homomorphism $T\to A$ that sends $t$ to $t(0,0)$, $g\cdot\phi$ is the homomorphism sending $t$ to $g(t(0,0))$, i.e., $(0,0)$ translated by $t$ and then rotated $90^\circ$ about the origin.

The second example is the carrying function of grade school arithmetic. See [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3072368?seq=1) for more on that.

Finally, a page by David Corfield offers ten [intuitions about cohomology](https://ncatlab.org/davidcorfield/show/intuitions+about+cohomology).